# Add & remove active class from a navigation link via php?

Tags: javascript, php, navigation, include

I have a php-navigation in index.php and include in this index.php different contents depending on the clicked navigation-tag.
i have now the problem that i want to add/remove "class="active"" when a page is included. maybe there is a non-javascript-solution, but also with javascript, i can't manage it now for hours...

Many thanks for help!

```
Navigation:

<li class="<?php echo ($page_id == 'Home' ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="index.php?go=home" class="activator">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo ($page_id == 'Konzept' ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="index.php?go=konzept" class="activator">Konzept</a></li>

...


<?php

if (isset($_GET['go']))
{
    switch($_GET['go'])
    {

        case 'home':    include('home.html');
                        $page_id == 'Home';
                        break;
        case 'konzept': include('konzept.html');
                        $page_id == 'Konzept';
                        break;
        ...
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a simple syntax error to me

```
<?php echo ($page_id == 'Home' ? 'active' : '')?>
```

Your string already began with `"` therefore you need to use `'` or `\"` to escape the quote.

As long as your navigation construct comes AFTER the isset, then you're good to go.

There is one last thing though, if the page doens't have a `go` in the query string, `page_id` will never be set and you'll get `undefined index` errors, so define it outside of the scope of the isset first.

```
<?php

$page_id = false;
if(isset(.....
```

Comment: THANK U.the problem was in the order of navigation and php-part.the $page_id i set now in home.html, konzept.html etc.. that works fine!